# How to handle seasonality when using relative errors

Tags: correlation, error, seasonality, prophet

I am using a model that forecast predictions for DAUs (daily active users). The DAU dataset is seasonal, so I'm trying to figure out the right "error" function for my model.

(The model I'm using Prophet https://facebook.github.io/prophet/ )

[image]

The green line is the prediction, the black line is the real data raw.

I am using relative error to calculate the error rate. The relative error formula is: `(prediction - real)/prediction.`

What's obvious here is that the formula will weight the troughs a lot more than the peaks, since the trough has smaller values.

What are the typical ways to account for this in the formula? I asked chatgpt and I got the following response https://pastebin.com/iEhNfP3q

Some of it makes sense, such as converting the values to logarithmic scale. I'm wondering if there is a "standard" way to handle such cases though.

I'd appreciate some guidance, thank you!

Comment: Only you can know the right "error" function for your model. It depends on how costly different errors are and whether the cost depends on the level of DAU.